# Insert a text string

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I want to insert a text into my string

```
#!/bin/bash

result=(4,51.0,60.0,70.2,888,91)

result2=$(echo "${result:2}" | sed -r 's/,/;/g')
echo "$result2"
```

I want my final output to be

```
Intemp=51;humidity=60;cold=70.2;heat=888;fan=91
```

Any help is welcome and thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you using an array with a single value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ result='4,51.0,60.0,70.2,888,91'

$ echo "${result#*,}" | awk -v tags='Intemp,humidity,cold,heat,fan' -F',' -v OFS=';' '
    BEGIN{split(tags,t)} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=t[i]"="($i+0)} 1
'
Intemp=51;humidity=60;cold=70.2;heat=888;fan=91
```

Comment: Great solution. please explain ($i+0) and the terminating 1. thanks

Comment: $i+0 converts anything starting with a digit to a number so `5foo` or `5.0` become just `5`. `1` is a true condition causing awk to invoke its default action of printing the current record - an **extremely** common awk idiom.

Comment: Hi Ed, This is the second time you have help me . Very much grateful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Write it out with

```
result='4,51.0,60.0,70.2,888,91'
sed -r 's/([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*)/Intemp=\2;humidity=\3;cold=\4;heat=\5;fan=\6/' <<< "${result//.0}"
```

Comment: Hi Walter, Thank you once again for taking time to reply